# DNS unknown followed by ipv6 address

Tags: dns, windows-domain

I set up a DNS for testing but when I go to DNS manager and click run `nslookup` I got "default server unknown addressee fe80:..."

**What I did**

I created A records with the same IP with the DNS same with reverse lookup zone and PTR all traffic is forward to ISP as forwarders and I still get the error

I also used Microsoft script to make ipv4 favorable over ipv6

Any suggestions?